# Jquery Select Dropdown to add or remove a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I am building a web application where you can mark TV shows as "Want to Watch", "Currently Watching", "Finished Watching", or "Stopped Watching." There is a  dropdown to select between these. If "Currently Watching" is selected, two more dropdowns should also be displayed for a user to enter their last watched season and episode. However, I am having trouble getting the jQuery to work properly

HTML

```
<select name="updateTvStatus" class="form-control" id="updateTvStatus">
    <option value="4" selected>Want to Watch</option>
    <option value="1">Currently Watching</option>
    <option value="2">Finished Watching</option>
    <option value="3">Stopped Watching</option>
</select>
<div id="last-watched" class="hidden">
    <select name="updateLastSeason" class="form-control" id="updateLastSeason">
        <option value="0">Select Season:</option>
        <option value="1">Season 1</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
    </select>
    <select name="updateLastEpisode" class="form-control" id="updateLastEpisode">
        <option value="0">Select Episode:</option>
        <option value="1">Episode 1</option>
        <option value="2">...</option>
    </select>
</div> <!-- /last-watched -->
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#updateTvStatus").change(function() {
        var TVstatus = $("#updateTvStatus").val();
        var ishidden = $('#last-watched').hasClass("hidden");
        if (TVstatus == 1 && ishidden == TRUE) {
            $('#last-watched').removeClass("hidden");
        } elseif (TVstatus != 1 && ishidden == FALSE) {
            $('#last-watched').addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are `TRUE` and `FALSE`? And what specific problem are you having?

Comment: In line 4, You are looking for $('.last-watched'), which is searching for a an element with 'last-watched' as the class name. Shouldn't it be $('#last-watched')?

Comment: Seems to work fine https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/XgaZEV When you say "TV shows" (plural), are you creating multiple copies of the same HTML above with the same (duplicate) IDs?  You really need to elaborate on what "work properly" means.

Comment: The problem is that when I click on "Currently Watching", it does not display the other two dropdowns. I have a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cxkaxthj/

@PaulAbbott, for me, your codepen just hangs at "Loading...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. else if (elseif) - syntax error.
2. Since JS is case sensitive, you'll ve to change TRUE/FALSE to true/false.
3. You've specified class selector instead of id selector. Pls change $('.last-watched') to $('#last-watched').

(And you may use === instead of == for strict comparison). 
So, a completed code ll look like this to work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
      $("#updateTvStatus").change(function() {
        var TVstatus = $("#updateTvStatus").val();
        var ishidden = $('#last-watched').hasClass("hidden");
        if (TVstatus == 1 && ishidden == true) {
           $('#last-watched').removeClass("hidden");
        } else if (TVstatus != 1 && ishidden == false) {
           $('#last-watched').addClass("hidden");
       }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for . But this is what you want for :

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#last-watched').hide();
$("#updateTvStatus").change(function() {
 var TVstatus = $("#updateTvStatus").val();
   if(TVstatus == 1){
        $('#last-watched').show();
    }else {
        $('#last-watched').hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
```